# How to link Qt codes to C++ codes (or C) in Mac using Macports?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, macports

I have installed Qt using Macports.  However, I do not know how to link Qt into the code ... what is the exact command to compile the code, the include path, library path and the name of the library.  Could any one help me with this?  I use clang and g++ as the main C++ compiler.

```
#include <Qdebug>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cout << "Test compilation.";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use QtCreator,  In addition to this you must use <QDebug> instead of <Qdebug>

Comment: Not directly answer my question but thanks anyway.

Comment: Qt is a very extensive library, you need many flags to compile it, so if you want a good editor you should use QtCreator. If you do not want at least you should use qmake to generate an appropriate Makefile.